# C++ - Shuffling a vector of objects

Tags: c++, vector

I am trying to make a deck of cards, I have a vector of card objects but when I use my shuffle function and print the deck they are all in the same order as they were when they were made.

Here's my playingCards class:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <random>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

class playingCards {
private:
    struct card {
        char suit;
        char value;
    };

    const int deckSize = 52;
    vector<card> deck;

public:
    playingCards();
    void printDeck();
    void shuffle();
};

playingCards::playingCards() {
    deck.reserve(deckSize);

    for (int i = 0; i < deckSize; i++) {
        int setSuit = i % 4;

        if      (setSuit == 0) deck[i].suit = 'D';
        else if (setSuit == 1) deck[i].suit = 'H';
        else if (setSuit == 2) deck[i].suit = 'S';
        else if (setSuit == 3) deck[i].suit = 'C';

        int setValue = i % 13;

        if      (setValue == 0)  deck[i].value = 'A';
        else if (setValue == 9)  deck[i].value = 'T';
        else if (setValue == 10) deck[i].value = 'J';
        else if (setValue == 11) deck[i].value = 'Q';
        else if (setValue == 12) deck[i].value = 'K';
        else                     deck[i].value = '0' + (setValue + 1);
    }
}

void playingCards::printDeck() {
    for (int i = 0; i < deckSize; i++) {
        cout << deck[i].value << deck[i].suit << endl;
    }
}

void playingCards::shuffle() {
    auto rng = default_random_engine {};

    std::shuffle(begin(deck), end(deck), rng);
}
```

I've also tried to pass by reference my vector into the shuffle function like so:

```
void playingCards::shuffle(vector<card>& deck) {
    auto rng = default_random_engine {};

    std::shuffle(begin(deck), end(deck), rng);
}
```

This didn't work either. Any help would be appreciated, I'm new to using vectors so I really don't understand what could be happening here.

Comment: For the first i values, you will get all 0 for the setSuit, is that right? For the setValue, you will not get anything, as deckSize is 52

Comment: You can access vector deck directly why do you need to pass it as param?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
deck.reserve(deckSize);
```

That doesn't add any elements to your vector, it only reserves space for them. So the size of your vector is zero, and when you shuffle it, nothing happens. The rest of your constructor, which sets (non-existent) elements of the vector, as well as your `printDeck` function, are both undefined behavior. Use `resize` instead.

```
deck.resize(deckSize);
```

In fact, it would be better to just remove the `deckSize` variable altogether, and just use `deck.size()`.

Comment: Changing it to resize solved the problem, and getting rid of deckSize made it simpler as well, thank you!

Comment: I see it the same way. The deck size should be a constructor parameter; this would make the whole thing much more generic (e.g. for to have different card game sub classes)

Answer (score 3):

You have to use

```
deck.emplace_back(value)
```

in order to create the actual vector. You just reserved the allocated memory which does not instantiate the vector. Beware of using `deck[i]`, this can cause undefined behavior, instead, use `deck.at(i)`. For this specific question, use `deck.emplace_back(value)` instead of `deck[i].`

Comment: Agreed, but you should be aware, that `deck.at(i)` (bounds checked) is much slower than `deck[i]` (non-bounds-checked). Safety comes with a cost... Doesn't matter in this tiny example, but if your'e working with thousands of iterations of thousands of strings, it makes a huge difference. So I would perhaps change "Do not use" to "Be aware of and use only if necessary"